# Can you open a Python shell in Atom editor?

Tags: python, atom-editor

You can open multiple tabs in the Atom editor, and have a multiple column layout as well. However, I am not being able to find out how to open a Python shell inside Atom so that I can load a Python script in the Python interactive shell.

Does anyone know the steps to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think there is. I downloaded it last night and didn't see anything like it in the default installation. That doesn't mean you can't hack it. Atom is a hackable text-editor that I'm sure can be added.

Comment: Why do you want to open a shell, as opposed to running your Python program with the `script` plugin?

Comment: Not sure what the script plugin is about. I want to load my functions and variables to an interactive Python shell so I can test things one by one before writing a script. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 33):

The [script package](https://atom.io/packages/script) is likely what you want, it allows you to test your code by running part or all of it at a time:

[image: Screenshot of Script Package]

You can install it by opening the settings view with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> switching to the `Install` panel and searching for script.  You can also install from the command line by running:

```
apm install script
```

Technically what you are asking for is closer to the [Terminal Plus package](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus), as opens up a terminal pane from which you can load the python interactive environment by entering `python`.

[image: Screenshot of Terminal Plus Package]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it covers all possible bases!

Comment: Note: Script package fails to run selected line(s) of Python code, it prints a disclaimer when you execute particular line(s) of code. I would suggest 'Hydrogen' package for REPL functionality.

Answer (score -1):

You need to go into: `Packages --> Settings view --> Install packages and themes` and then type "terminal" and install the one that starts with "platformio":

[image]

Install it and then you will have the + button down there.